# OK to put lots of content within single link?

Tags: html

This works fine on my computer but im wondering if its a good idea in terms of accessibility, etc.

I have a page of product listings, and I want each listing to link to a product page. The listing is made up of an image and a few photographs of text.

I want the entire listing area to be a link, including white space. So rather than make the images and text links individually, ive put the entire div in a link.

As I said, this is working fine on my computer, but is a good idea for a production site?
Thanks

Comment: As a user, I'm always annoyed when I click whitespace and find my browser going to some page.

Comment: "A good idea for a production site" is a matter of opinion. Can you rephrase the question to be less subjective?

Comment: @Isaac I dont really mean anything by a 'production site'. I just meant it was working fine for me on my computer, but obviously there are different considerations for a live site. Thanks

Comment: @jdin My point was that this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Just asking if something is a "good idea" is inviting discussion, not asking a specific, objectively answerable question.

Comment: Please don't ask questions like "How do I do what this website is doing:  SomeSpammyWebsiteIWantToDriveTrafficTo.com?"  It makes you look like a spammer that wants to drive traffic to your spammy website.  If applicable, you can take a screenshot of the website (to demonstrate what you are asking for) instead of linking to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the right-side video links on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/).  These are block-layout spans wrapped in `a` tags.  (Not that just because Google does it means it's a good idea, but...)

If the area has a `:hover` color (as these do), then it should be clear enough to the user that this is an action item.

Answer (score 2):

If it's like a grid or something, and you give a visual cue when the user moves the mouse over the row (background color changing etc) along with the cursor becoming a hand, it should be fine if you use the whitespace as part of your link.

Answer (score 1):

If you want me in your website's audience, I would prefer if you wouldn't. When switching between windows, clicking in the window area is the quickest way to switch focus between windows. If like 80% of your window is really a link, I would find that annoying. I think I am not the only one.

The way it sounds there is also plenty of area which you can make behave like a link, such as the image, and the text in the grid. If that would be clickable, that would be big enough a target to hit.

Also imagine your app being used on a touch screen. These sometimes imsinterpret drag (scroll/zoom) and tick gestures. Which is annoying if everything responds to clicks.

Answer (score -1):

Syntactically it's invalid, you cannot put block elements (div, p, table) inside of inline elements (span, a, strong, em).

Comment: not quite, HTML5 specifies `a` elements as `transparent` which allows them to contain block-level elements. You just have to make sure you're using the HTML5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`.

Comment: True, but if you looked at his site, he's using the xhtml doctype.